# How to get a DLL loading process handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, code-injection

I'm trying to get the handle to the process which loaded a dll from the dll.

My approach is:
in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH I call EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc,NULL);

my EnumWindowsProc implementation is the following:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    if(GetCurrentProcessId() == GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,NULL)){
        MessageBox(hWnd,L"I loaded your dll!",L"it's me",MB_OK);
        return TRUE;
}
    return FALSE;
}
```

the problem is that GetCurrentProcessId() == GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,NULL) is never true (if i place the messagebox call outside the if block everything works but it gets called once for every listed window).

Is there any other way to get to the point? Is this approach totally wrong or am I just missing something?

Thanx in advance

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId returns the thread id, the 2nd parameter gets the process id. (Note: You should not go crazy in DllMain, there are only a few functions that are actually safe to use in that function)

Comment: I know, but my problem is I need to do all the stuff inside DLLmain because my dll is injected in a running process.

Answer (score 4):

Use [GetCurrentProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess), which returns a pseudo-handle to the current process. If you need a real handle, pass in the pseudo-handle to [DuplicateHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle).

Note that it is very dangerous to do too much in `DllMain`. Calling anything other than `KERNEL32` functions is quite dangerous, and even then there are some `KERNEL32` functions that you shouldn't be calling. See the [`DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) documentation, [this document](https://web.archive.org/web/20101029013644/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/driver/kernel/DLL_bestprac.mspx), and [several](https://web.archive.org/web/20140424141226/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/04/23/118979.aspx) [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2004/01/27) [posts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2004/01/28) [from](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2007/09/04) Microsoft developers recommending against doing too much in `DllMain`.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to simply use [GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179(VS.85).aspx) whenever you need the handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [GetProcessHandleFromHwnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318087(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake:

GetWindowThreadProcessId does not return the process ID but the thread ID.

Your program must be written like this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    DWORD process;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,&process);
    if(GetCurrentProcessId() == process){
        MessageBox(hWnd,L"I loaded your dll!",L"it's me",MB_OK);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```