# How can I get host application handle in dll project with Delphi without passing handle parameter

Tags: delphi, winapi

I Have a dll project. I have to get host application handle. I Can't pass handle from host application to dll project because the host application is not mine.

The host application runs on second monitor but when the host application calls my form (dll) the form shown in first monitor. I have to detect host application screen coordinates or i have to detech the host application runs on first monitor or second monitor.

Comment: Please define "host application handle". What is this thing? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: [Same Q for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365190/how-to-get-a-dll-loading-process-handle)

Comment: @TLama: There is no such thing as **the** active window. Each thread (or group of input-attached threads) can have an active window, that is queried by calling [GetActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292.aspx).

Comment: @TLama: That's called the *foreground window*. It is returned when calling [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505.aspx). The *foreground window* is also always the *active window* of the foreground thread.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks! Then I'm taking back my comment(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for top-level windows in your process. Find them like so:

1. Call `GetCurrentProcessId` to obtain your process ID.
2. Call `EnumWindows` to enumerate all top level windows.
3. In the enumeration callback, for each top level window, call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to obtain the process ID that owns the window. Any that match the process ID found in step 1 are from your process.

The problem that you face is that step 3 might identify multiple such windows. You can call `GetWindow` passing `GW_OWNER` to obtain the owner of the window and use that to trim down the field of candidates. What you perceive as being the main window is likely to have no owner, but the other top level windows may well be owned. Even this cannot be guaranteed to trim the field down to a single candidate and you very likely will need to come up with some additional logic.