# How to find out to what process my dll is attached?

Tags: c++, process, dll-injection

Before my dll file gets injected to a process, I want to check if it actually is the process I want it to inject. Is there a way to achieve this, so I could abort the injection process if its the wrong process?
Thank you in advance for any help!

```cpp
int APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        if (process == theprocessiwant)
        {
            //call my stuff....
        }
    }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: [GetCurrentProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess) maybe.

Comment: [GetModuleFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)

Comment: Maybe this helps (if not a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365190/how-to-get-a-dll-loading-process-handle

Answer (score 0):

[GetModuleFileNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea) will give you the complete path of the executable of whose process you have injected into.  Compare this path against your predefined executable path.

Answer (score -1):

Okay thank you for your suggestions, I found a working way!

```cpp
DWORD targetProcessId;
int APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (_stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "target.exe") == 0)
            {
                targetProcessId = entry.th32ProcessID;
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        if (GetCurrentProcessId() == targetProcessId)
        {
           //MY Code
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```